# What is the probability that the sum of their squares is at most one?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two real numbers are randomly chosen from the interval
[0, 1]
What is the probability that the sum of their squares is at most one?
This question does not make sense to me because the probability of any real number is $\frac{1}{\infty}$.

How can I possibly find the sum of infinity then or have I understood the question wrongly?
Edit: This question is right out of the script book that we use in class so there is no answer yet.

Comment: Choosing the two real numbers is the same a choosing a point in the square $[0,1]^2$. The points for which the sum of the squares of their coordinates is at most $1$ are those inside the closed circular disc of radius $1$. The area of the part of the disc that falls inside the square $[0,1]^2$ is a quarter of the disc and therefore it is equal to $\pi/4$.

Comment: Your question is contradictory. In the title, you said that what's the probability the sum 'eqal' (I assume you mean equal) 1, while in the description, you asked for the probability if the sum is at most 1.

Comment: It is true however, that the problem is badly posed until they specify what is the distribution of the choice of the points. But usually when they leave it like that they mean the Lebesgue measure (usual area) on $[0,1]^2$

Comment: The OP's trouble seems to come from them applying to continuous distributions some principles/techniques they learnt, which are only pertinent for discrete distributions. In this respect, to know that the real answer of their specific question is $\pi/4$ might not help them much...

Comment: edited it for clarity. I do not understand the use of the radius. why did you use this concept if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Rocca If you have a point $(x,y)$ in the plane, then $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(0,0)$, the origin. This follows from applying Pythagoras on the triangle formed by dropping a perpendicular from $(x,y)$ to the $X$-axis. Since $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ is the same as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq 1$, we get that the condition on the sum of the squares is equivalent to the condition on the distance from the origin.

Comment: @acetone I think I understand a bit better now. It makes sense but then the probability should be pi/4?

Comment: Yes, the probability space is $[0,1]^2$, the probability (which is their job to have somehow specified) is the usual are of the event (a subset with area) and the event in question is $\{(x,y):\ x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$. The area of that subset is $\pi/4$ by the argument above.

Comment: @user545497 If we were to find the area then it would be $$pi*r²$$ = Pi isn't it? Why is it pi/4 then?

Comment: @Rocca: That's the area of the entire unit circle.  Your random values can't be negative, so it can't include any part of the unit circle outside the first quadrant.  (See my answer for more details.)

Answer (score 5):

When a random variable $X$—say, the rainfall in Los Angeles in a given month—can take on any value within a continuous interval such as $[0, 1]$ with uniform probability, the probability of $X$ taking on any specific value in that interval is not a positive number.  That is to say, it is $0$; for instance,

$$
P(X = 1/2) = 0
$$

In plain words, this says that the probability that the rainfall in that month is exactly $1/2$ inch would be $0$.  It is a peculiarity of the way that probability is defined that this does *not* mean that it is impossible.  After all, the rainfall must be *some* value within that range (we're presuming), so they can't all be impossible.

But by the same token, the probability cannot be any positive number, because otherwise, they'd all be the same positive number (by uniformity), and their combined probabilities would sum to an infinite value.  The only value that makes sense is $0$.

But then what does it mean to say that the rainfall is uniformly distributed in the interval $[0, 1]$, if no single value has a positive probability attached to it?  It means that the probability that the precipitation falls (sorry) within a given smaller interval is equal to the length—the *measure*—of that smaller interval, divided by the measure of the entire interval $[0, 1]$.  If we denote this measure by $\mu(\cdot)$, then we can write this symbolically as

$$
P(a < X < b) = \frac{\mu([a, b])}{\mu([0, 1])}
$$

provided that $0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1$.  Since the length of an interval is the difference between its endpoints, we can rewrite this *for our specific situation* as

$$
P(a < Z < b) = \frac{b-a}{1-0} = b-a
$$

So the probability that the rainfall is between $1/3$ and $1/2$ inches would be $1/2 - 1/3 = 1/6$, the probability that the rainfall is between $0$ and $1/e$ inches would be $1/e - 0 = 1/e$, and so forth.

---

Dealing with two independent random variables that are each uniformly distributed in $[0, 1]$ is not much more difficult.  Call this new random variable $Y$ (perhaps it's the rainfall in San Francisco in a given week), and we can also write that

$$
P(c < Y < d) = d-c
$$

(again, providing that $0 \leq c \leq d \leq 1$) as we did with $X$.  And what does the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent mean?  It means only that the value of $X$ has no influence on the value of $Y$, and *vice versa*.  It does not mean that $X$ and $Y$ can't be equal, or that they can't both be positive at the same time, or anything like that.  Their values are simply not dependent on each other.  In particular, it means that

$$
P(a < X < b \text{ AND } c < Y < d)
    = P(a < X < b) \times P(c < Y < d)
    = (b-a)(d-c)
$$

If we visualize this situation on the Cartesian grid, with the value of $X$ on the $x$-axis (naturally) and the value of $Y$ on the $y$-axis, this combination of the two intervals corresponds to a rectangle bounded by the four points $(a, c)$, $(a, d)$, $(b, c)$, and $(b, d)$, and the probability that $X$ and $Y$ *both* fall within their respective intervals is equal to the *area* of that rectangle.  Very convenient!

It turns out that under very broad circumstances, we can determine the probability of any combination of values of $X$ and $Y$ as being equal to the area of some corresponding region in the $x$-$y$ plane.  In the problem you cite—

> Two real numbers are randomly chosen from the interval $[0, 1]$. What is the probability that the sum of their squares is at most one?

—the corresponding area is the region where

$$
X^2+Y^2 \leq 1
$$

constrained by the mutual conditions $X \in [0, 1], Y \in [0, 1]$.  Compute the area of that region, and you'll have the desired probability.

Answer (score 0):

I think they mean to regard the point as chosen from a uniform distribution over the square $[0,1] \times [0,1].$ Since this square already has area $1,$ your probability will just be the area of the part of the unit circle in quadrant 1.

Comment: Please see my comment on main.

Comment: @Did OK will delete soon... I thought the OP might not have heard about uniform distributions for such problems; I didn't go through that giving the theory of it, since I didn't want a long answer and thought OP could look in a text about it.

Comment: These are valid points. Actually, since I posted my comment, the OP's real intent with their question has become less clear...

Comment: @Did So guess I'll leave it for now, at least until OP clears up his question.

Comment: @Did I am taking this question right out of the book, I would like to understand how to find the probability.

Comment: @Rocca Yeah, except that we still do not know whether you want explanations about the "1/infinity" conundrum that you described in your question or about details of the computation leading to the answer pi/4 which coffeemath explained.