# Choosing three numbers from $(0,1)$

Tags: geometry, puzzle

> If we choose $a,b,c$ randomly from $(0,1)$, is the probability $p$ that $a^2+b^2+c^2\le 1$ :
>
> a) equal to $\pi/8$,
>   b) smaller than $0.55$,
>   c) larger than $0.5$,
>   d) a rational number.

This is a weird problem a friend send to me. I don't really know how to approach this problem.

My idea was to note that picking three points $a,b,c$ from $(0,1)$ is the same as picking a point $P=(a,b,c)$ such that $a,b,c\in (0,1)$ in 3D-space. Then, $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is the length of the radius $\overline{OP}$ of one-eight of the sphere centered at the origin $O$. We want $\overline{OP}\le 1$.

Edit: is the probability equal to 
$$P=\frac{\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{4}{3}\cdot \pi\cdot 1^3}{1^3}=\frac{2}{3}\pi?? $$

Comment: Geometrically, the total space is the unit cube in the first "octant" (all coordinates positive). The good solutions are those points which sit inside the unit sphere.

Comment: If you don't know how to approach this problem, here is an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710358/what-is-the-probability-that-the-sum-of-their-squares-is-at-most-one/2710598#2710598) to essentially the same question, only in two dimensions.

Comment: Almost!.  Note that $\frac 23 \pi>2$ so that can't be right.   Check your multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is fine, but there is an error in the computation.